# R - ggplot2 re-order of categorical variable (issue with reorder func)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to re-order the categories of a variable of my `ggplot`.

I specifically added `letters` before the categories of the variable to indicate the order. 
Because I summarise with other variables the **order** of the levels got messed up.

```
               value      mean
1            a Sleep 539.72637
2             c Work  60.62189
3   e Travel/Commute  84.50249
4          f Cooking  54.24129
...............................
```

But it should be

```
a Sleep
b Personal care
c Work
d Studies/library
...
```

Here is the summarised data of my plot.

```
data = structure(list(value = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
                               8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
                               21L, 22L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
                               13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L), .Label = c("a Sleep", 
                                                                                             "c Work", "e Travel/Commute", "f Cooking", "g Housework", "h Odd jobs", 
                                                                                             "i Eating", "j Child care", "k Care for others", "m Leisure", 
                                                                                             "u TV/Radio", "v Others", "t Visiting/Socialising", "p Telephone/Online Communication", 
                                                                                             "b Personal care", "d Studies/library", "s Religious", "l Shopping", 
                                                                                             "q Computing/Internet", "n Highbrow", "o Sport", "r Civic"), class = "factor"), 
           mean = c(539.726368159204, 60.6218905472637, 84.5024875621891, 
                    54.2412935323383, 133.980099502488, 37.4378109452736, 92.773631840796, 
                    39.6393034825871, 49.8880597014925, 55.3109452736318, 126.119402985075, 
                    19.1417910447761, 61.6169154228856, 7.86069651741294, 3.70646766169154, 
                    2.46268656716418, 6.00746268656716, 41.6417910447761, 5.08706467661692, 
                    12.3880597014925, 4.27860696517413, 1.56716417910448, 531.689440993789, 
                    118.086956521739, 92.5590062111801, 25.167701863354, 71.2422360248447, 
                    67.7391304347826, 91.5776397515528, 27.0310559006211, 29.1801242236025, 
                    62.583850931677, 161.391304347826, 20.1614906832298, 61.0434782608696, 
                    4.6583850931677, 0.31055900621118, 3.21739130434783, 5.3416149068323, 
                    32.1739130434783, 16.1614906832298, 10.5962732919255, 7.57763975155279, 
                    2.29813664596273)), .Names = c("value", "mean"), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                               "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -44L))
```

Could you help me to re-introduce the order of the categories ? 
I guess I have to use `desc` somewhere.

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(x= value, y=mean, fill = value )) +
geom_bar(stat="identity") + theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Some have [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916779/sorting-of-categorical-variables-in-ggplot) `reorder` but this is not what I want to do

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(x= reorder(value, mean), y=mean, fill = value )) +
geom_bar(stat="identity") + theme_minimal()
```

Comment: Use `level` argument of `factor` function to specify order in your data.frame.

Comment: It is quite complex because my original dataset is a set of lists and I would prefer not doing this by hand.

Comment: But you added "a", "b", "c"... by hand, no?

Comment: Do the same with `level`.

Comment: it implies that I have to delete the levels I have already and then re-`paste` ...

Comment: Not necessarily. This is my solution, but some better solution can come up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relevel the variable using sorted levels of the 'value'variable (I created a new one for comparison purposes):

```
data$value2 <- factor(data$value, levels = sort(levels(data$value)))

ggplot(data=data, aes(x= value2, y=mean, fill = value2 )) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") + theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks - I wanted to avoid doing this but apparently it is the only solution

Comment: Why did you want to avoid it, and what part of the solution is undesirable to you?